# layout works different on different mobile android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am making a video calling app i have made the designs for both persons.One who make call(sender) and other who receive call(receiver) but the problem i face is that on one mobile i will get my own stream and opponent stream but on other mobile which have different android version i will get the opponent stream but my own stream is not showing it will be in background.

[samsung s4 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG8EG.png) this image show me both the streams.

[LG G3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ufTx.png) not showing its own stream.it will be in background

But i have made the same layout for both sender and receiver.I think this problem is due to different android version on each mobile.please help me how to solve this issue.

sender:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/whencalling"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#DB2727"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       >


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/muteVoume"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:button="@drawable/mutedrawable" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/switchCameraAction2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:button="@drawable/cemeradrawable" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:button="@drawable/micdrawable" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>





        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/whencallhappens"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
          >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        >


                        <Space
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/llPrimary">


                            <io.skyway.Peer.Browser.Canvas
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/svPrimary"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <Space
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

                <LinearLayout

                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:id="@+id/llSecondary"
                    >

                    <io.skyway.Peer.Browser.Canvas
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/svSecondary"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="20px"
                    android:layout_height="10px"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>





            <Button

                android:id="@+id/callend"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/endcall" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

receiver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/whencalling"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#DB2727"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/muteVoume"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:button="@drawable/mutedrawable" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/switchCameraAction2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:button="@drawable/cemeradrawable" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:button="@drawable/micdrawable" />

    </RelativeLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar2"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar2"></include>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/whencallhappens"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llPrimary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <io.skyway.Peer.Browser.Canvas
                        android:id="@+id/svPrimary"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Space                        
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llSecondary"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <io.skyway.Peer.Browser.Canvas
                 android:id="@+id/svSecondary"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"                       
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"                    
                  />

                </LinearLayout>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="20px"
                    android:layout_height="10px" />

            </LinearLayout>




            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/Not_received"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                >

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ReceiveCall"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/callpick" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/EndCall"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"                    
                    android:background="@drawable/endcall"                       
                    />


                <Space
                    android:layout_width="300px"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/EndVideoCall"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/endcall" />

                <Space

                    android:layout_width="350px"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think this is due to different android versions. Can you send code snippet where you make and receive calls.

Comment: @Mansuu.... xmls for sender and receiver are same it works fine on s4 but when i use it in different mobile it will hide the small block stream which is our own stream

Comment: You have fixed height and width of some views. It may cause problems on small screen devices.I think You must check this out again.

Answer (score 0):

**Use The Scalable Size Unit :**

-To add sdp to your project Using Android Studio and Gradle :

```
   dependencies {
        compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
   }
```

-for Example Use in xml :

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/spin_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_120sdp"/>
```

Comment: android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp" put this in your code.

Comment: every or just on parent

Comment: use dimension like (for example : @dimen/_20sdp )

Answer (score 0):

Use this to support all resolution devices : 
https://github.com/intuit/sdp

**sdp** for margin/padding and **ssp** for font size.

Comment: i think its not bout support to multiple device but how a particular layout is not showing on some devices